# composer vendor/bin files not being detected on Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu, composer-php, behat

Yesterday I've just installed Laravel with Behat on my VM Ubuntu 15.10.
Everything works fine, running the command `$ vendor/bin/behat --init` successfully created the `features/` folder

but today something is weird, when running the `$ vendor/bin/behat` its saying `vendor/bin/behat: line 1: ../behat/behat/bin/behat: No such file or directory`

What's inside the `vendor/bin/behat` file? 
This first single line `../behat/behat/bin/behat`

accessing the actual location works `$ vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat` which basically means the `file DOES exists`

Please note that the issue is the same for the files in `vendor/bin` like `doctrine` `phpspec` etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having relative path problems. If your current directory contains `vendor/` and you execute `vendor/bin/behat`, then `../behat/behat/bin/behat` doesn't exist because it's going one directory up from your current directory, not `vendor/bin/`. For example:

```
$ cd $HOME/project
$ vendor/bin/behat
vendor/bin/behat: line 1: ../behat/behat/bin/behat: No such file or directory
```

That relative path becomes `$HOME/project/behat/behat/bin/behat` and not `$HOME/project/vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat` (note `vendor` present in the second path)

You need to be inside `vendor/bin/` when executing `behat`:

```
$ cd $HOME/project/vendor/bin
$ behat
...
```

However, I don't see this being an issue with the latest `behat` install, [line #1](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/blob/master/bin/behat#L1) is a well formed shebang. I think you might want to destroy your `vendor` install, update composer, etc, and [reinstall Behat](https://github.com/Behat/Behat#installing-behat). Those files should not start with relative paths.

**EDIT:**

According to the composer docs, it [creates symlinks to package binaries](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md#what-happens-when-composer-is-run-on-a-composer-json-that-has-dependencies-with-vendor-binaries-listed-), as seen in the [source code](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php#L244). You can verify this by running `ls -l vendor/bin` (all symlinks will have a `->` pointing to their destination path). It would seem your original `php composer.phar require ...` was corrupt from the beginning.

Comment: Yeah actually I resolved the issue by deleting vendor folder and composer.lock then issuing composer install again. The interesting part is, the files in vendor/bin/* doesnt contain the relative path but instead the actual code to which they are pointing. Ex. Vendor/bin/behat has the same content with vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat. Any idea?

Comment: @Daskul - According to the composer docs, it [creates symlinks to package binaries](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md#what-happens-when-composer-is-run-on-a-composer-json-that-has-dependencies-with-vendor-binaries-listed-). You can verify this by running `ls -l vendor/bin` (all symlinks will have a `->` pointing to their destination path). It would seem your original `php composer.phar require ...` was corrupt from the beginning.

Comment: If you're curious, here's [where the magic happens](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Installer/LibraryInstaller.php#L244) in composer installing binaries.

Comment: I see. Could you add it on your answer so I can accept it